# Is this problem NP-hard?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete, binary-programming

Is the following problem NP-hard?

> Let $Ax=b$, where $a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}, b_i \in \{0,1\}, x_j \in \{0,1\}$. 
> Decide, wether there is a solution or not.

Comment: Do you want to find all solutions ? Or do you just want to decide whether there is a solution ?

Comment: whether it exist one solution

Comment: What's the definition that you're using about NP?

Comment: NP given a solution $(x_1, \ldots , x_n)$ it can be verified in polynomial time. But I want to proof it is at least NP-Hard.

Comment: Also if it isn't and you know a way to find a solution in polynomial time let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are given $A$ and $b$ and want to find $x$, this is the [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem, which is one of the original 21 NP-complete problems.  Row $i$ corresponds to an element, and column $j$ corresponds to a subset.  The (constant) value of $a_{i,j}$ indicates whether element $i$ appears in set $j$.  The (variable) value of $x_j$ indicates whether set $j$ is selected.  If $b_i = 0$, then $x_j=0$ for all $j$ with $a_{i,j}=1$, and row $i$ can be removed.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain briefly (or if you can with detail) how are they equivalent? The exact cover is for subsets while the above problem is a linear system of boolean variables.

Comment: I updated my answer with more detail just now.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!