# determine whether if a linear system has binary solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, binary-programming

Is there any general method that helps to determine a linear system have binary solutions?

E.g. For a linear system
$$
Ax=b
$$
Where $A \in \mathbb{N}^{m\times n}, b \in \mathbb{N}^{m\times 1}$. Is there any efficient way to determine if there is any solution fits this constraint $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This problem is a well-known NP-Complete problem.  The best-known algorithms take time exponential in the size of the problem data.  Unless P=NP (something that most computer scientists consider unlikely), there won't be an efficient polynomial-time algorithm for this problem.

This is problem MP1 in Garey and Johnson's *Computers and Intractability* (page 245.)

Comment: is there a name for the well-known problem? 0-1 integer programming?

Comment: NP-complete even if $A$ and $b$ are binary: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959335/is-this-problem-np-hard

Comment: This is the 0-1 integer linear programming feasibility problem.